# Node client "Endorsement has failed error" submitting transaction - HLF Minikube

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, minikube

I'm testing my chaincode in a node client app but I'm not able to submit a transaction. 
**Everything works fine if I invoke/query the chaincode within my peer pods**, but if i try to do it in my node client, only the querying works. 
I have 1 orderer as Solo and 3 peers within K8S minikube. No TLS.
I'm using Fabric 1.4.

If I change the connection options to:

```
discovery: true
asLocalhost: true
```

I get the following error:

```
 "message": "Endorsement has failed",
"stack": "Error: Endorsement has failed\n    at DiscoveryEndorsementHandler._endorse 
 "message": "14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses"
```

---

If I change the connection options to:

```
discovery: false
asLocalhost: true
or
discovery: false
asLocalhost: false
```

I get the following error:

```
"message": "No orderers assigned to the channel",
"stack": "Error: No orderers assigned to the channel\n    at BasicCommitHandler._commit
```

---

If I change the connection options to:

```
discovery: true
asLocalhost: false
```

I get the following error:

```
"message": "Endorsement has failed",
"stack": "Error: Endorsement has failed\n    at DiscoveryEndorsementHandler._endorse 
"message": "14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed",
"stack": "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed
```

I'll share my connection profile:

```
---
name: connection.profile
version: 1.0.0
client:
  tlsEnable: false
  organization: WheyOrg
  connection:
    timeout:
      peer:
        endorser: 300
      orderer: 300

channels:
  wheychannel:
    orderes:
       - orderer.whey.cluster
    peers:
      peer1.whey.cluster:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
        discover: true

      peer1.lab.cluster:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
        discover: true

      peer1.carrier.cluster:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
        discover: true

organizations:

  WheyOrg:
    mspid: WheyMSP
    peers:
    - peer1.whey.cluster

    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca-wheyorg

    adminPrivateKey:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/whey.cluster/users/Admin@whey.cluster/msp/keystore/priv_sk

    signedCert:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/whey.cluster/users/Admin@whey.cluster/msp/signcerts/Admin@whey.cluster-cert.pem


orderers:

  orderer.whey.cluster:

    url: grpc://192.168.64.2:30750

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.whey.cluster
      grpc-max-send-message-length: 4194304

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/whey.cluster/tlsca/tlsca.whey.cluster-cert.pem

peers:

  peer1.whey.cluster:

    url: grpc://192.168.64.2:30751

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/whey.cluster/tlsca/tlsca.whey.cluster-cert.pem

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.whey.cluster
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000

  peer1.lab.cluster:

    url: grpc://192.168.64.2:30851

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/lab.cluster/tlsca/tlsca.lab.cluster-cert.pem

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.lab.cluster
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000

  peer1.carrier.cluster:

    url: grpc://192.168.64.2:30951

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carrier.cluster/tlsca/tlsca.carrier.cluster-cert.pem

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.carrier.cluster
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000


certificateAuthorities:
  ca-wheyorg:
    url: http://192.168.64.2:30054

    httpOptions:
      verify: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/whey.cluster/ca/ca.whey.cluster-cert.pem

    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw

    caName: ca-wheyorg

  ca-laborg:
    url: http://192.168.64.2:30054

    httpOptions:
      verify: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/lab.cluster/ca/ca.lab.cluster-cert.pem

    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw

    caName: ca-laborg

  ca-carrierorg:
    url: http://192.168.64.2:30054

    httpOptions:
      verify: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./development/network-config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carrier.cluster/ca/ca.carrier.cluster-cert.pem

    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw

    caName: ca-carrierorg
```

---

k8s peer yaml:

```
# YAML for launching the peer
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: whey-peer
  labels:
    app: whey-peer
spec:
  serviceName: whey-peer
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whey-peer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whey-peer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whey-peer
        # Image used
        image: my_image 
        # Uncomment the following during development/testing of the image
        # imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: FABRIC_CFG_PATH
            value: /var/hyperledger/config
          - name: FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC
            value: DEBUG
          - name: ORDERER_ADDRESS
            value: whey-orderer-clusterip:30750
          - name: ORG_CONTEXT
            value: whey
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
            value: localhost:30751
        volumeMounts:
        - name: whey-peer-ledger
          mountPath: /var/ledger
        - name: dockersock
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      volumes:
      - name: dockersock
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata: 
      name: whey-peer-ledger
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: general
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi

---
# Expose the port 7051 as ClusterIP
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whey-peer-clusterip

spec:
  # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
  # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
  # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
  selector:
    app: whey-peer

  ports:
    - name: whey-peer-clusterip
      port: 30751
    - name: whey-peer-cc-clusterip
      port: 30752

  type: ClusterIP

---
# Expose the port 30751 as node port -  NEEDED if you
# are interested in connecting to the Pods from the Host
# machine - keep in mind you would need the IP for the node
# port service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whey-peer-nodeport

spec:
  # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
  # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
  # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
  selector:
    app: whey-peer

  ports:
    - name: whey-peer-nodeport-751
      port: 30751
      nodePort: 30751
    - name: whey-peer-cc-nodeport-752
      port: 30752
      nodePort: 30752

  type: NodePort
```

---

I've been trying to figure out what I'm missing here but with no success so far :|
What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need more info.

Thank you*

Comment: I would investigate your DNS setup as the error message suggests - the pods will be using the K8s DNS service (normally core-dns), while your Node client is presumably not in a pod and using a different DNS.

Comment: There's a typo in your connection profile - 3rd line under `channels:` should say `orderers`.